# DragMove() and MouseDragElementBehaviour won't work in the same window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I am creating a WPF/xaml application with

WindowStyle="None"

So because of this I am having to use

```
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        // Begin dragging the window
        this.DragMove();
```

To make it so the window can be dragged around the screen. However I also want to make images within the window drag-able which I planned to do using

```
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="65" Width="203" Margin="0,278.271,14.434,82.5" Source="Images/Implementation1.png" Stretch="Fill">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Image>
```

The issue is that I can't get them both to work on the same window as they will only function if the other is switched off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` is defined on the whole window, thus interfering with the trigger for `MouseDragElementBehavior`.

Add a `Border` to your window, give it a `Background` (`Transparent` is ok, just don't leave it without a background) and listen to `MouseLeftButtonDown` event on the border. Do the `DragMove()` in the handler for the event.

You can put the border as a title of the window, or you can put it behind the content.